# Does the babel-preset-env pollute the global scope like babel-polyfill does?

Tags: babeljs, webdriver-io, babel-polyfill, babel-preset-env

I need to use **ES6** code and also **Object.entries** in my code. After looking into babel I saw that they recommended to use `babel-preset-env`. But I am writing step definitions in webdriverIO and they recommend to use `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` so that it doesn't **pollute** the global scope. Let me know if I can use babel-preset-env and still not pollute global scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is mostly **no**. Babel 'preset-env' with 'useBuiltins' will indeed polyfill/pollute the global scope. Particularly, I think it uses core-js to do so, which polyfills the global scope by default.

Sources:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7267#issuecomment-373560397